# Response message ClassCastException: Cannot cast java.util.LinkedHashMap (id=173) to com.sw.Employee

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp

Am getting cannot cast exception in Listener when I am trying to send LinkedHashMap as request at producer end using Spring AMQP.

Request -

```
Map<String, Object> reqMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
Employee emp = new Employee();
reqMap.put("empObj", emp);
reqMap.put("comp", "XYZ");
template.convertAndSend(reqMap);
```

Respons-

```
void handleMessage(Map myReqMsg){
 Employee emp = (Employee)  myReqMsg.get("empObj");
}
```

Exception at Consumer End :-
ClassCastException: Cannot cast java.util.LinkedHashMap (id=173) to com.sw.Employee

Log Trace -

```
WARN  [.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer]: Execution of Rabbit message listener failed, and no ErrorHandler has been set.
org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener method 'handleMessage' threw exception
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessageListenerAdapter.invokeListenerMethod(MessageListenerAdapter.java:457)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(MessageListenerAdapter.java:358)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:546)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:472)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$001(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:61)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$1.invokeListener(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:110)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:611)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:454)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:474)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:458)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$300(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:61)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:551)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to com.steelwedge.amqp.util.Employee
    at com.steelwedge.amqp.producer.TestMessageHandler.handleMessage(TestMessageHandler.java:25)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.util.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:273)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessageListenerAdapter.invokeListenerMethod(MessageListenerAdapter.java:451)
    ... 12 more
```

Thanks,
Sekhar

Comment: Show your Listener configuration and StackTrace, please

Comment: Yes, please provide the full stack trace and a DEBUG log if possible.

Comment: As Artem asked; we also need to see your configuration. Also, it Employee `Serializable`. I suggest you add some debug logging - such as `System.out.println(myReqMsg)` and/or run with a debugger and see what is being passed to your `handleMessage`. On the face of it, what you are seeing makes no sense to me, but we are clearly missing some crucial information.

Answer (score 1):

You should do a conversion:
i.e.

```
ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
om.convertValue(object, clazz);
```